# Can an app start a component in another app through explicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Can App A start a component in App B through explicit intent?

I understand that general use of an explicit intent is to start a component within the same app. Implicit intents are used to cross process boundary.

Scenario:

1. App B defines and uses a custom permission "foo"
2. App A uses
       PackageManager API to identify App B (app which defined "foo")

   Can App A start a component within App B through **explicit intent**?

I don't think this is possible because explicit intent needs- app package and component name.

> if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager
>                       .checkPermission("foo",
>                               pk.packageName))
>                       results.add("package name: "+pk.applicationInfo.packageName+ "    class name:
>   "+pk.applicationInfo.classNa);
>           }

Class name is null. So, per my understanding there is no way inter-app communication is possible through explicit intent just by relying on PackageManager APIs. In Android 5, you can call AIDL Services only through explicit intent but at dev-time the caller needs to know package and component name of app exposing the AIDL. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Can App A start a component within App B?

App A can try. Whether App A will succeed depends on several things, including whether the component is exported and whether the component is secured by a permission.

> I don't think this is possible because explicit intent needs- app package and component name.

The application ID and component name are both strings. Apps can use strings. Correctly getting the application ID and component name may take some work, depending upon the relationship between App A and App B.

As a counter-example, the only way to bind to a service on Android 5.0+ is via an explicit `Intent`. Hence, if App A wishes to bind to a service exported by App B, App A has no choice but to create an explicit `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

No way. If you want to start something that's outside your app you have to declare a implicit intent. Otherwise android will look for it inside your package, probably not gonna find anything and crash.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> You'll typically use an explicit intent to start a component in your
>   own app, because you know the class name of the activity or service
>   you want to start.

Under "Intent Types" - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

So, typically you will not... but you can do this however it is not straightforward. To create a proper explicit intent, you will need the application context and the class.

To get the context of another application:

```
 createPackageContext (String packageName, int flags)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int)

For the class, you can request 'Activity' and 'Service' classes from package manager. You could also try to use reflection. You can also use the fully qualified string name of the package and assume it is correct and/or will not change. If you want, you can include a stub of the class in your app, thereby obtaining a reference to it (if you have access to the source or a stub library).

If there are permission restrictions, you will need to request permission.